# parse.com Linker Error xcode 6 swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform, xcode6

After I installing xcode6 I got some errors with parse.The project was working just fine in beta versions of xcode 6. I think i might be parse.com that is not compatible with xcode6. I think I have added all the frameworks properly[image]

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem,

first, download the latest SDK version from Parse.com

second, I noticed that when I run it NOT on the iPhone 6 simulator it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You're targeting the iOS Simulator, which the Parse framework does not seem to support. So:

- Clean project.
- Change the destination from iOS Simulator to iOS Device.
- Build.

That's all you need to do.